# why does this error happen when I name a layer (TypeError: call() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name')?

Tags: python, keras, tensor

I have a deep network in Keras and I used the following code:

```
g_layer = DepthwiseConv2D(kernel_size, use_bias=False, padding='same',name='glay')
decoded_noise = g_layer(bncv11,name='GB')
```

but it produces this error and does not allow me to name this layer, but I should name all layers because I want to set weights based on the name later. could you please tell me what should I do to solve this problem?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 141, in 
>       decoded_noise = g_layer(bncv11,name='GB')
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py",
>   line 457, in **call**
>       output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
>
> TypeError: call() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

Comment: when you run `g_layer(bncv11,name='GB')` then system runs `g_layer.call(bncv11,name='GB')` (or `g_layer.__call__(bncv11,name='GB')`) and this method doesn't get `name`. Maybe you have to use `g_layer.name = "GB"` to change name ? OR you could keep names in separated structure - ie. dict `layers = {g_layer: name}` or `layers = {g_layer: {"name": name}}`

Comment: Thank you. if I only named DepthwiseConv2D, it will be true? and do not name  g_layer separately?

Comment: Your `g_layer` is already named in the definition i.e. `name=glay`. Why are you trying to name it when you're just calling the layer on some input? It will work if your have `decoded_noise = g_layer(bncv11)`. Also, you cannot pass a name argument when calling a layer on an input.